# How does one write an inequality constraint in package NlcOptim

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization

I am using factor model and I am looking for U matrix that would rotate my factors in a way to suit a better interpretation of the factors. I am using NlcOptim to find such matrix U, where I specify equality constraints as well as one inequality constrain.

However, I am not sure if the way I wrote the inequality constraint is correct. The syntax I am using currently is:

```
# Constraints
con <- function(x){
  # equality constraints:
  f=NULL
  f=rbind(f,x[1]^2 + x[3]^2 - 1)
  f=rbind(f,x[2]^2 + x[4]^2 - 1)
  f=rbind(f,x[1]*x[2] + x[3]*x[4] - 0)
  f=rbind(f,x[3]*loading[1,1] + x[4]*loading[1,2] -0)

  # inequality constraint:
  c=rbind(c,(x[1]*loading[6,1] + x[2]*loading[6,2] + x[3]*loading[6,3]-0)
  return(list(ceq=f,c=NULL))
}

# Objective function
obj <- function(x){
  U  <- matrix(c(x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4]),nrow=2)
  xx <- F_pre%*%U[,2]
  
  out <- 0.5*t(xx)%*%xx/length(F_pre)
  as.numeric(out)
}

# Solve the optimization problem to obtain U matrix
sol <- NlcOptim::solnl(c(diag(2)),objfun=obj,confun=con)
```

Here I am not sure if the inequality equation is written in the right form. So it should be as

```
x[1]*loading[6,1] + x[2]*loading[6,2] + x[3]*loading[6,3] =< 0
```